# Finding active record entries without nil associations in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

These are obviously not my actual Models but they serve as an example. I have the following class definitions.

```
class Movie < ActiveRecord::Base
    has_one :opening
    has_one :opening_info, through: :opening
end

class Opening < ActiveRecord::Base
    belongs_to :movie
    has_one :opening_info
end

class OpeningInfo < ActiveRecord::Base
    belongs_to :opening
    # OpeningInfo has a opening_date attribute in the DB
end
```

I want to find all movies that have either a non existent Opening, an existent Opening but a non existent OpeningInfo, or a existent Opening  and existent OpeningInfo but a nil opening_date. I can do it as follows

```
ids = Movie.joins(:opening_info).where.not(opening_infos: { opening_date: nil })
Movie.where("id not in (?)", ids)
```

But this query was slow, ~2/3 seconds, and ideally I'd like it to take no longer than other ordinary queries, ~100-500 ms. What's the rails way of doing this?

Answer (score 0):

Have you added indexes to your columns you're querying?  This should speed things up a great deal.

Comment: Yes I have, anyways I'm simply curious. Set subtraction seems like a clumsy solution.

Answer (score 0):

Figured out the answer

```
Movie.includes(:opening, :opening_info).where("opening_infos.opening_date is null or opening_infos is null or openings is null")
```